# What are the mathematical topics required to understand the given paper?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability

I came across this paper [here](http://asa.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1121/1.5024234), which I would like to understand and reproduce if possible.  It is too mathematical for me and I am having difficulty in understanding the mathematical concepts behind this work. I don't know whether it is linear algebra, calculus or something else which is required to understand the paper. It would be great if some of you can suggest the required mathematical background needed to understand this paper. So that I can learn those and have a look at the paper later.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a research-level question which is better to be asked on MathOverflow.

Comment: You should be more precise what aspect you do not understand? For example, cite equations by there numbers and tell us what part you do not understand. @AlexFrancisco: Not sure if the question is at the research level (it is just a question about what mathematical prerequisites this paper has.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Being on-topic on MO does not imply (at all) being off-topic here. Besides, it doesn't seem to be a math paper, so I don't think this would be well-received on MO.

Comment: almost impossible to say from an abstract where the maths might go.